# android toolbar menu item button?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

is it possible to add a button label like this as a toolbar action menu item?

[image]

I tried the following code below

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_submit"
    android:title="@string/submit_titlecase"
    android:visible="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/primary_btn"
    app:showAsAction="always|withText" />
```

And it appears blank?
If i remove the android:icon, it appears the text but not the button sourrounding outline

Answer (score 0):

Define a menu item in the following manner:

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_submit"
    android:title="Submit"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

(Basically, if you show as action and you don't provide an icon, the title is shown as a button on the toolbar.)
But if you want it specifically to look like a button like you've put up in your question, make a drawable/mipmap file looking exactly like that and then add `android:icon="@drawable/icon"` (or `@mipmap/icon`) into your menu item code.